# Iterating through layer using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, iteration

I'm a beginner in ArcPy and I want to perform some tasks using ArcPy but I am not getting results.

I have two layers named `survey` and `survey selection` in my current MXD. I want to create map document for each layer in `survey selection` and this is my script:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") 
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
titleElement = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT")

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("survey selection")
for row in rows: 
    titleElement = row.VendorFarm 
    query = '"FID"=' + str(row.FID)    
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("survey selection", "NEW_SELECTION", query)     
    df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()      
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

del rows 
del row
```

Comment: There's quite a bit of example code in the documentation, which would allow you to get closer to your goal. I'm curious as to why you've selected the *second* DataFrame.  Do you have two, or are you getting an error there?

Comment: I've 3 dataframes and the layers are in the second data frame

Comment: For selecting each entity in a layer your best bet is a cursor, look for that. For saving polygons as images, I am confused.

Comment: To compliment @Vince try typing "zoomToSelectedFeatures" or "ExportToTIFF" into the help file? In fact if you go to this [page](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/dataframe-class.htm)  the code is practically written for you in example 2. As always go to the help file first...